# What is the chance of getting brawlers in a big/mega box vs a brawl box?

Tags: brawl-stars

I can see the chances of getting new brawlers in brawl stars for big boxes and mega boxes (they're actually the same).
No chances for new brawlers from 'regular' brawl boxes (that I can see) are listed.
Is there any way I can find those statistics? If so, what are the chances in relation to the big boxes/mega boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop rates are for **ONE** brawl box. If you open a big box, as it is equivalent to 3 brawl box, it will do three brawl box draws. This means you are able to get max three special items (brawlers, star powers or gadgets). Such as if you are lucky, you get a brawler on the first draw, you get coins and power points on the second draw and you get a gadget on the third draw, then you have some coins, a brawler and a gadget in a box. Similarly, as a mega box is equivalent to 10 boxes, the system will do 10 draws.

Comment: Then why are the chances of getting new brawlers the same for both mega boxes and big boxes?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins It is because the stats are all for one brawl box.

Comment: So one brawl box, one big box, and one mega box all have the same chances of getting a new brawler is what you’re saying?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins The big box is 3 brawl boxes, so the system draws 3 times, and so the chance of getting at least one brawler from a big box is the same as getting at least one brawler from three brawl box. The mega box is 10 brawl boxes, so the probability of getting at least one brawler from a mega box is the same as the probability of getting at least one brawler from 10 brawl boxes.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do it, first go to the mega box in the shop, click on it but do not confirm. Next, press the "i" button and you get your chances (the button in the corner of the window, not the one in the corner of the light blue section). From there, you can check your drop rates.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112639/discussion-on-answer-by-thatz9-brawl-stars-brawl-box-chances).

Answer (score 0):

The drop rates depending on the disadvantage of the brawler.

**If you unlock a legendary brawler, your chances decrease deeply.**

This is determined by a legendary brawler being good over all others. To see your stats/chances, go to the shop, click on a mega box/big box, and click the information button on the left-hand side. The chances are numerous and decimal-placed, which meaning that brawlers are hard to get.

**The Brawl Boxes, Big Boxes, and Mega Boxes have benefits to the drop rate.**

You are more likely to get a brawler out of a big box than a mega box. I know that this may sound confusing, but it is true, even though Mega Boxes are more dependable.

## Increasing your Chances

Of course, opening boxes and what you can get out of them can be unpredictable, but I can help with increasing your chances so it's more guaranteed. To unlock more brawlers, you must:

- Simply open boxes. If you don't get a brawler out of that box, it adds luck chance.
- Strive and gem (Purchase gems and spam boxes, recommendable to "gemmers")

> Use Unofficial Techniques (Hack, easily get free brawlers from this, not my recommended strategy)

These are the best 3 ways out of the many ways you can get a brawler.

## Box Boosts

As I mentioned before, getting good brawlers decreases your chances of getting another one. If I might interfere, the boosts from boxes are amazing:

- x1 Box Boost from Brawl Box
- x5 Box Boost from Big Box (Best Boost)
- x10 Box Boost from Mega Box

These add boosts to your box chances regardless if they are low.

## Conclusion

Go ahead and try my techniques of increasing your chances! Your most likely to get a brawler from a big box by chance.

Comment: Although your answer is beautifully laid out, it still doesn't tell me how I can find the chances of new brawlers from regular boxes. Also, "You are more likely to get a brawler out of a big box than a mega box. I know that this may sound confusing, but it is true, even though Mega Boxes are more dependable."--This seems wrong, Both mega boxes and big boxes have the same chances per box. It is true however that you can increase your chances by buying bigs instead of megas because they're cheaper, but the chances are the same for each.

Comment: Read the beginning of my answer and you will find how you can see your chances! :) (Chances unpredictable) @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins

Comment: I’m wondering about regular boxes, not big boxes or mega boxes. The only reason the chances in bigs and megas would be useful is if you could tell me how to calculate the chances of regular boxes in relation to bigs and megas

Comment: That depends on how many brawlers you have. @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins